# Enterprise library 5.0 new database

Tags: c#-4.0, enterprise-library

I'm using the enterprise library 5.0 to establish a database connection.
after setting the  config file I'm trying to create a new database instance through this line of code :

```
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

but I'm getting this error :

activation error occured while trying to get instance of type database key""

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the config is correct? Could you post it please?

Comment: @ClaraOnager: dear clara i successfully solve it...I corrected the config file and it worked(there was an error in connection string)

Comment: Please add your config file connection setting code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the references to it and mark them to be copied locally (see here how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx)